# MySQL - Joining the same table twice but grabbing different results

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I previously asked a question in regards to the same situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957478/mysql-group-multiple-rows-while-retaining-differences/58957585?noredirect=1#comment104171258_58957585) but since I was so vague about my query, the provided solution didn't work for my specific case. Here's my second attempt at resolving this:

I have a series of tables that are connected in strange ways... Here's the end result I'm trying to achieve with my SELECT query:

```
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|------------|---------------|
| id | company | city     | province | manager_name  | manager_email | staff_name | staff_email   |
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|------------|---------------|
| 1  | aaa     | toronto  | ON       | John Smith    | john@aaa.com  | Steve Chan | steve@aaa.com |
| 2  | bbb     | sudbury  | ON       | Tom Bell      | tom@bbb.com   |            |               |
| 3  | ccc     | hamilton | ON       | Bill Miller   | bill@ccc.com  | Jill Smith | jill@ccc.com  |
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|------------|---------------|
```

It may be confusing without seeing the database structure, but here's my query:

```sql
SELECT
  f.id,
  f.firm_name company,
  f.city,
  f.province,

  -- manager
  CONCAT(b.first_name, ' ', b.last_name) manager_name, 
  b.primary_email manager_email

  -- staff
  -- CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', s.last_name) staff_name,
  -- c.primary_email staff_email

  -- manager (alt attempt)
  -- CASE
  --   WHEN r.user_role_types_id = 7 THEN max(b.primary_email)
  -- END AS manager_email,

  -- staff (alt attempt)
  -- CASE
  --   WHEN r.user_role_types_id = 21 THEN max(b.primary_email)
  -- END AS staff_email

FROM
  projects p1

-- projects
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(fiscal_year) max_year, -- latest of the fiscal years
    firms_id
  FROM
    projects
  GROUP BY
    firms_id
) p2
ON p1.fiscal_year = p2.max_year
AND p1.firms_id = p2.firms_id

-- firms
JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    firm_name,
    is_cancelled,
    deleted,
    a.city,
    a.province,
  FROM
    firms

    -- address
    JOIN (
      SELECT
        firms_id,
        city,
        province
      FROM
        addresses
    ) a
    ON a.firms_id = id
) f
ON f.id = p1.firms_id

-- roles
JOIN (
  SELECT
    projects_id,
    users_id,
    user_role_types_id
  FROM
    project_user_roles
) r
ON r.projects_id = p1.id

-- managers
JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    primary_email
  FROM
    users
) m
ON m.id = r.users_id
-- AND r.user_role_types_id = 7

-- staff
-- JOIN (
--   SELECT
--     id,
--     first_name,
--     last_name,
--     primary_email
--   FROM
--     users
-- ) s
-- ON s.id = r.users_id
-- AND r.user_role_types_id = 21

WHERE
  p1.deleted = 0 -- project not deleted
  AND f.is_cancelled = 0 -- firm not cancelled
  AND f.deleted = 0 -- firm not deleted
  AND
  (
    r.user_role_types_id = 7 -- managers only
    OR r.user_role_types_id = 21 -- staff only
  )

GROUP BY
  f.id

ORDER BY
  f.firm_name
```

Notes:

- I've left some of my previous / alternate attempts in there (commented out)
- Both managers and staff are stored in the same table with the same fields `first_name`, `last_name` and `primary_email`... The only thing that separates a manager from a staff is their `r.user_role_types_id`, which is specified in the roles table

  - manager = 7, staff = 21
- **I seem to be able to only grab the manager or the staff, not both... this is my main issue**

Commenting out the `manager` section at the top, the `GROUP BY` section at the bottom, and un-commenting the `CASE` statements was my latest attempt at getting both of these fields, but it produced results like the following:

```
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
| id | company | city     | province | manager_email | staff_email   |
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
| 1  | aaa     | toronto  | ON       | john@aaa.com  |               |
| 1  | aaa     | toronto  | ON       |               | steve@aaa.com |
| 2  | bbb     | sudbury  | ON       | tom@bbb.com   |               |
| 3  | ccc     | hamilton | ON       | bill@ccc.com  |               |
| 3  | ccc     | hamilton | ON       |               | jill@ccc.com  |
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
```

While this brought me close to my goal, I still needed to do the following:

- group duplicate lines into 1, retaining both emails

  - this specifically is what brought me to ask my previous question like I did
- grab the `manager_name` and `staff_name` fields

I'll be happy to clarify any of this further if needed, but basically, I just need to be able to grab both the `manager` and `staff` details... Any ideas?

Also let me know you have any suggestions on renaming / re-wording this question for better visibility... It was hard to find the words to use.

Comment: P.S. Yes I've read [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499863/mysql-join-same-table-different-result-set) along with many others, but the answers are very specific to the use-cases of the OPs and couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out with help from both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58957585/4075723) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/168541/175789)! Here's my new query, just in case somebody else in this strange situation finds themselves here:

```sql
SELECT
  f.id,
  f.firm_name company,
  f.city,
  f.province,
  f.region_type region,
  f.industry_type industry,

  -- manager
  MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN r.user_role_types_id = 7
      THEN CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)
    END
  ) AS manager_name,
  MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN r.user_role_types_id = 7
      THEN u.primary_email
    END
  ) AS manager_email,

  -- staff
  MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN r.user_role_types_id = 21
      THEN CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)
    END
  ) AS staff_name,
  MAX(
    CASE
      WHEN r.user_role_types_id = 21
      THEN u.primary_email
    END
  ) AS staff_email

FROM
  projects p1

-- projects
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(fiscal_year) max_year, -- latest of the fiscal years
    firms_id
  FROM
    projects
  GROUP BY
    firms_id
) p2
ON p1.fiscal_year = p2.max_year
AND p1.firms_id = p2.firms_id

-- firms
JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    firm_name,
    is_cancelled,
    deleted,
    a.city,
    a.province
  FROM
    firms

    -- address
    JOIN (
      SELECT
        firms_id,
        city,
        province
      FROM
        addresses
    ) a
    ON a.firms_id = id
) f
ON f.id = p1.firms_id

-- roles
JOIN (
  SELECT
    projects_id,
    users_id,
    user_role_types_id
  FROM
    project_user_roles
) r
ON r.projects_id = p1.id

-- users
JOIN (
  SELECT
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    primary_email
  FROM
    users
) u
ON u.id = r.users_id

WHERE
  p1.deleted = 0 -- project not deleted
  AND f.is_cancelled = 0 -- firm not cancelled
  AND f.deleted = 0 -- firm not deleted
  AND f.industry_type != ''

GROUP BY
  f.id

ORDER BY
  f.firm_name
```